# used for expressing a relative position?

Tags: meaning-in-context

found an expression like this at [wordreference.com](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/t%C3%B4) under the definition of "to":

> 18. (used for expressing a relative position):
>     *parallel to the roof.*

What does the word "**relative**" mean here?

"*in relation to*" or "*not absolute*" ?

Comment: ***relative*** = ***in relation to***. In the example, ***parallel*** wouldn't really mean *anything* if we can't answer the question *Parallel to **what**?* There *is* such a thing as "absolute **location**" (a latitude / longitude grid reference, for example), but ***parallel*** must *always* be relative to *something*.

Comment: ...even in the expression ***parallel lines***, which means 2 or more lines that are all parallel ***relative to each other***.

Comment: also gave the following examples besides the existing example :
the woman standing to the left of the car

Comment: You don't say what word was being defined, but I'm guessing it was **to**. 'Left' and 'right' only make sense if they are relative to something else.

Comment: yes, you're right, that's why I gave a few more examples. I want to ask you too. Can we say that they are included in the relative position (in relation to ) group ? It can only produce parts that normally lie distal to the level of amputation. The sternum consists of a plate lying ventral to the thoracic cavity. by the way i'm talking about in relation to ( in connection with )

Comment: I find your medical description to be quite confusing. A sternum consisting of a plate??

Comment: If you want to alert me that you are asking a question about my comment, you need to begin with @KateBunting.  Yes, _distal to_ and _ventral to_ are included in the category of 'relative positions'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.

You cannot be parallel in an absolute sense (nor above, below, beside, etc).

In practice, you will know that this is how the word must be used, because if you try to use it in an absolute sense, the sentence will not make sense *alone*.

e.g. *"I was impressed that it was that parallel".

However, if it was preceded by something that gave context, it could be understood:

*"The had cemented the post next to the building without using a spirit level. I was impressed that it was that parallel."*

Here 'to the building' is 'understood'.

Comment: I want to give a few more examples. Can we say that they are included in the relative position *(in relation to )* group ?


It can only produce parts that normally lie **distal to the level of amputation**.  
     
The sternum consists of a plate lying **ventral to the thoracic cavity.**

Comment: Maybe it's because IANAS (I Am Not A Surgeon), but ***distal to the level of amputation*** makes no sense at all to me. Besides which, anyone who's having trouble understanding the "meaning" / use of ***to*** when used for expressing a relative position should probably start with simpler "positional" adjectives than ***distal, ventral*** (words that I'm sure are completely opaque ***to*** most native speakers).

Answer (score -1):

In this case, the word "relative" means "in relation to" or "compared to something else".

When you say "distal", "ventral", "parallel", etc., these words have no meaning at all without something to compare them to. Once that reference point is established, though, there's no doubt what the meaning is. This is what *"in relation to"* means.

The other meaning of "relative", *"not absolute"*, is mostly used for assessments or opinions that will have different meanings if taken from different contexts. Words like "good/attractive/smart/skilled" and so on don't have any absolute value, and only have meaning relative to some context.

For instance, a professional billiards player at the bottom of his league is obviously a very, very good player relative to the average player because he's professional. But equally obviously, he's a very bad player relative to other pros in the league. This example shows that "good" is a relative term, in the sense of "not absolute", and has no meaning without a relative context.

Comment: yes, you're right, that's why I gave a few more examples. I want to ask you too. Can we say that they are included in the relative position (in relation to ) group ? It can only produce parts that normally lie distal to the level of amputation. The sternum consists of a plate lying ventral to the thoracic cavity. by the way i'm talking about in relation to ( in connection with )

Comment: @emilywenly See my comment on [your new question about this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/326683/113306)