# distal to ventral to?

Tags: grammar

. Can we say that they are included in the relative position (in relation to ) group ?  By the way i'm talking about **in relation to ( in connection with )** Freedictionary '' to '' 13. (used for expressing a relative position):

It can only produce parts that normally lie **distal to the level of amputation.**

The sternum consists of a plate lying **ventral to the thoracic cavity**.

Comment: Sorry, but really this: **produce parts** that normally lie distal: is very weird. Your anatomical description is not accurate. The sternum is a BONE, so are you saying it was replaced by a plate? Or what? Please make your description more accurate. Thanks.

Comment: Also, in English parts related to bodies often is used by forensic people: body parts, and that means they are separated from a body....

Comment: I don't understand at all what you're asking. What does "they" refer to in your question? What is "the relative position group"?